# Find the optimal rank 1 and 10 approximation of a matrix

Tags: matrices, matlab, matrix-rank, svd

In Matlab, I have read a black & white image and converted its pixels into `double` values. Let's denote it by `A` ($300$ by $150$). I need to find the optimal rank-$1$ and rank-$10$ approximations of a matrix in Frobenius norm. I am a bit confused on the Frobenius norm part.

I used the command

```
k = svds(A,k) returns the k largest singular values.
```

Thus, I used

```
one = svds(A,1);
ten = svds(A,10);
```

However, how do I use the Frobenius norm so I can find the optimal rank-$1$ and rank-$10$ approximations?

EDIT: is it safe to say that the optimal rank 1 is basically my matrix S of my singular values but it has only the biggest value and the rest are zero? The same goes if I wanted rank 10 then the 10 biggest values and the rest zero? Thus just by doing the command svds I have basically have found the optimal approximation of rank 1(or 10)?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "the optimal rank 1 and rank 10 of a matrix".

Comment: What I suspect you mean is "the optimal rank 1 (or 10) **approximation** of a matrix", i.e. the matrix $B$ that minimizes $\|A - B\|$ under the constraint that its rank is (at most) 1 (or 10). If this is the case, please [edit] your question to make this clear.

Comment: Also, I suspect that you have written A(300,150) to mean that $A$ is a matrix of size $300 \times 150$. Please be aware that this is not standard mathematical notation (at least as far as I am aware).

Comment: hey @BenGrossmann Thank you very much for your input. Yes that s what I meant. I will edit the question

Answer (score 0):

Use the command `[U,S,V] = svds(a,10)`. From there, `U*S*V'` is the best low-rank approximation. The same thing works for rank $1$.

Comment: Hey. Thank you for replying. How exactly is Frobenius norm then used if we just used the svd command?

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure what you have in mind when you say "using the Frobenius norm". The [EYM theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation#Basic_low-rank_approximation_problem) guarantees that using the SVD in this way produces the best approximation relative to the distance defined via the Frobenius norm.

Comment: @Alex As an analogy, if we have the function $f(x) = x^2 - 5x + 6$ and we want to answer the question of which $x \in \Bbb R$ minimizes $f$, then we could answer with $x = -b/(2a) = 5/2$. In that context, how exactly is the function $f$ used?